Why does IEEE 754 define 1 ^ NaN as 1, and why do Java and Javascript violate this?
IEEE 754 defines 1 ^ n as 1, regardless of n. (I'm not paying $106 to confirm this for myself, but this paper cites page 44 from the 2008 standard for this claim.) Most programming languages seem to follow this prescription: Python, C, C#, PHP, Go, and Rust all return 1 for 1 ^ NaN. However, Java and Javascript both return NaN.

Why does IEEE 754 create this exception to the general rule of NaN propagation?
Why do Java and Javascript not follow the standard?


n is likely meant to be a number, so returning NaN where n is not anumber would not go against the standard.

IEEE 754 was mostly created with hardware in mind, so perhaps (I wasn't in the room) short-circuiting the base 1 made some things easier.

"but this paper cites page 44 from the 2008 standard" erm, how reliable is a paper that is literally a joke published on the 1st of April?

Yea that paper is not a legit paper. Check the first footnote: "∗Copyright c 2019 the Regents of the Wikiplia Foundation. Appears
in SIGBOVIK 2019 with the half precision of the Association for Computational Heresy; IEEEEEE! press,"

Anyway, regarding question 1. you have to ask the author(s) of IEEE 754, or in a related forum, why they created that exception to the rule; and similar for question 2. you must ask the authors of the specification of Java and Javascript

"Abstract Yes, this paper contains many layers of abstraction." This paper is a trusted source for sure.

from Wikipedia: "In general, NaNs will be propagated, i.e. most operations involving a NaN will result in a NaN, although functions that would give some defined result for any given floating-point value will do so for NaNs as well, e.g. NaN ^ 0 = 1."; ...

...  and javadoc of Math: "The special case behavior of the recommended operations generally follows the guidance of the IEEE 754 standard. However, the pow method defines different behavior for some arguments, as noted in its specification." and from the specification: "If the second argument is NaN, then the result is NaN."

I read the whole question twice and I'm still unsure if you mean the "power of" operator or XOR. Because I can assure you that if you believe the former you are definitely mistaking, neither C nor C# define such an operator -- and do not mistake libraries (pow and Math.Pow respectively) with language definitions.

Have you read the note in https://tc39.es/ecma262/2024/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-numeric-types-number-exponentiate? Seems pretty clear.

I assumed this question is not about the XOR operation (^), but the power of (Math#pow) method - "IEEE 754 defines 1 ^ n as 1, regardless of n" does not make sense if XOR is meant by "^"

I assumed that by ^ the OP was referring to the common mathematical symbol for exponentiation rather than any programming language's operator. Just like we might use ÷ for division or ✕ for multiplication even though neither of those are an operator in any mainstream programming language.

I am not on the IEEE 754 board, yet have used/studied the standard for decades.
Even if reasonable as an opinion, of course this is not authoritative.


Why does IEEE 754 create this exception to the general rule of NaN propagation?

Consider IEEE 754 defines 00 as 1.0 when 0.0, 1.0, infinity, undefined, etc. are all math candidates.  There simply is not a universal math result, yet for a computational result, returning 1 satisfies most computational uses.
IMO, this applies here, but even more so.  The idea the NaN represents some quantity x of non-deterministic sign and magnitude (potentially infinite) real and imaginary.  In all those case 1x results in 1.0.  So even with NaN, a result of 1.0 is at least reasonable.

Why do Java and Javascript not follow the standard?

Likely it was simply to code that way and that initial choice stuck.
Perhaps the designers were also off put by the spec's price and did not consider this corner case's ramifications.

"Perhaps the designers were also off put by the spec's price and did not consider this corner case's ramifications."  - I would have thought the simplest thing to do would be to forward all floating-point operations to C, since the JVM is implemented in C.

@k314159 How C handles pow(1, NAN) is not specified as adherence to IEEE 754 is not required for a compliant compiler/library.  Even when an implementation says it follows IEEE 754, there are so many cases that nuance mistakes are common.  Conversely, a number of C implementations do follow all, or nearly all, of the IEEE 754 spec, yet do not claim it does as the effort to back up the claim is too great.

@chux Actually, ISO C does specify that in annex F of the standard, which is normative but optional (i.e. it only applies to implementations that claim to support IEC 60559 a.k.a. IEEE-754). E.g. ISO C17, F.10.4.4: "... pow(+1, y) returns 1 for any y, even a NaN ...".

@njuffa Yes, "but optional" fulfills "not required".

@chux I was not commenting on "is not required" (we are in full agreement on that part) but on "is not specified". It is specified, applicable to C implementations that adhere to IEEE-754.

Regarding "and imaginary": The result would not be 1 if the NaN represented the product of i (which is the square root of -1) and positive or negative infinity.  Instead, it would be  positive or negative infinity, respectively, since 1^=^(2)=^−2.  Refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205546/1-to-the-power-i

@Andrew Answer amended.
